# Electron redirect page after click

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to convert my nodejs application into desktop app.

So, I want to redirect new page, after clicking the button. And I tried this ;

**This is from entry.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="goto-add-customer">Select</button>

    </div>

    <script>
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
        document.getElementById('goto-add-customer').addEventListener('click', () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('open-new-page');
        });
    </script>
```

**And here is my main.js**

```
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('entry.html');


 
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  ipcMain.on('open-new-page', () => {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'addCustomerPage.html'));
  });
});


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

However, when I click the button nothing happens. Can you help me ?

Comment: if all you need is just go to another page. you don't need all of this. in your client js code just set `window.location="your_html_file.html"` instead of of `ipcRenderer.send('open-new-page');` and btw in you configuration its not possible to do require in the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you need is just goes to another page. you actually dont need all of this. just change you html to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="goto-add-customer">Select</button>

    </div>

    <script>
     
        document.getElementById('goto-add-customer').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.location="./addCustomerPage.html";
        });
    </script>
```

that's all and you can remove the part from main.js

I can explain how to do that in the way of html -> main but its not required in your situation. and actually, as much as possible try to make it cross platform and not electron specific. if you still need it this way the comment and I'll explain

Comment: Thank you @eli chen, actually, I'm just trying to integrate my nodejs app into a desktop app.